# fixed Mail in android studio wthout showing send or recived mail

Tags: javascript, java, android

This is code I got online for sending mail in android studio using the Gmail API, but I need to fixed sender and mail I need to send at the same time as like sender hazem@gmail.com and receiver will be hazem11@gmail.com without showing which account I need to send mail and which mail I should have added to send.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton sendFabButton;
    EditText edtToAddress, edtSubject, edtMessage, edtAttachmentData;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
    ProgressDialog mProgress;
    private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
    private static final String[] SCOPES = {
        GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS,
        GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE,
        GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT,
        GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY,
        GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY,
        GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM
    };
    private InternetDetector internetDetector;
    private final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
    public String fileName = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

        findViewById(R.id.attachment).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Utils.checkPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, SELECT_PHOTO);
                }
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.changeAccount).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Utils.checkPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    startActivityForResult(mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), Utils.REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, SELECT_PHOTO);
                }
            }
        });

        sendFabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getResultsFromApi(view);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: i can't add all code link to download notepad with all code http://www.mediafire.com/file/0mnx3v83yr6y73j/API_Error.txt/file

Comment: What actually is your question? There is nothing in your post which asks a question...